# Ruby syntax error: unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a  block that seems to work independently but as I put it in a  code sample it fails with a syntax error:

```
9 def get_version(name, user, pass, type, organization, art_module, repos, version)
10  puts case
11  when type.match(/snapshot$/i)
12    p version
13    when version.match(/latest$/i)
14         string_object = open("https://artifactory.xxx.io/artifactory/api/search/versions?g=#{organization}&v=*.*.?&a=#{art_module}&repos=#{repos}", :http_basic_authentication=>["#{user}", "#{pass}"])
15         json_file = JSON.parse(string_object.read)
16         version_array = Array.new
17         json_file["results"].each do |version|
18           version_array.push(version["version"].sub /-.*$/, '')
19         end
20         #p unique_versions=(version_array.uniq).max
21    else
22         p "here"
23         string_object = open("https://artifactory.xxx.io/artifactory/api/search/versions?g=#{organization}&v=*.*.?&a=#{art_module}&repos=#{repos}", :http_basic_authentication=>["#{user}", "#{pass}"])
24         json_file = JSON.parse(string_object.read)
25         version_array = Array.new
26         json_file["results"].each do |version|
27           version_array.push(version["version"].sub /-.*$/, '')
28         end
29         p unique_versions=(version_array.uniq).min
30    end
31  when type.match(/release$/i)
32  ...


SyntaxError
==> default: -----------
==> default: C:\vagrant-chef\a2c27477ebffe71b9594bbbb58557887\cookbooks\dj_productivity_any\providers\dj_artifactory_version.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
==> default:          json_file["results"].each do |version|
==> default:                                      ^
==> default: C:\vagrant-chef\a2c27477ebffe71b9594bbbb58557887\cookbooks\dj_productivity_any\providers\dj_artifactory_version.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: `unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end` this error usually means you're missing an end or close-brace or close-parenthesis somewhere in the code above it...  `dj_artifactory_version.rb:26` this part says that the first error is on line 26, which means your problem is in the lines above line 26... you haven't indicated what the line-numbers are in your code so I can't pin down what LOC that is, but I'd be guessing it's in the `when version.match(/latest$/i)` section

Comment: One odd thing I notice is... you have nothing directly after the `case` keyword... normally... you are comparing something to each of the `when` statements... also -... are you trying to *nest* when statements without opening a new `case` statement? that just isn't going to work.

Comment: @TarynEast - included line numbers.

Comment: @TarynEast - ignore puts case.

Comment: Please don't use "Edit" or "Update" tags in your text. Simply insert the changes in your text where you would have initially. We can see what changed, and when, if we need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using case when what you really want is just plain ole if/else

You should *only* use case if you have *one* thing that you are testing which of several possibilities it is eg:

```
case my_string
when /blue/
  do blue stuff
when /yellow/
  do yellow stuff
when /red/
  do red stuff
else
   do something else
end
```

You should *not* use it to test multiple things eg what you are doing here:

```
case # nothing here to compare against the `when` cases
when type.match(/snapshot$/i) # here you are comparing type
when version.match(/latest$/i) # and now version
when type.match(/release$/i) # and now type again
```

also... you've got weird nesting that *will not work*. You code technically does this:

```
case # open the case statement
when type.match(/snapshot$/i) # first match
when version.match(/latest$/i) # second match
else # this counts as the else clause of the first case
end # this has now closed the case statement completely
# and now there's another when... without a case... which is why yuour code is borking
when type.match(/release$/i) # and now type again
```

What I *think* you're really trying to do is nest a second case statement inside the first one (if I'm wrong, correct me on this)>
If so... you really, really, really don't need case statements. Just use if/else like this

```
if type.match(/snapshot$/i) # first match
  if version.match(/latest$/i) # second match
  else # this counts as the else clause of the second if-statement
  end # this has now closed the second if-statement
elsif type.match(/release$/i) # and now we test a second option against type
end # and this closes the first if-statement
```

if you realy, really must use case statements, then you need to do a few things:
a) actually specify what you're testign in the case-statement - right after the word `case`
b) repeat the keyword `case` every time you are opening a new, nested set of them... eg:

```
case type
when /snapshot$/i # first case - first option (testing type)
  case version
  when /latest$/i # second case - first option (testing version)
  else # else clause of second case
  end # end of second case
when /release$/i # first case - second option (testing type)
end # end of first case
```

Note that the case-statement is absolutely overkill when there is only one thing to test against (eg the second case statement).

Comment: Thanks, did this with an if/elsif/else block.

Answer (score 1):

`when` is valid only inside a `case`, see that you have an `else` and `end` (that closes your `case`) and after it you have another `when` block (lines 30 and 31).

Indent your code and it will be easier to spot the error (probably you forgot to start a new `case` before line 13 then your indentation would be correct).